# Convert to Buffer from hex string in node and then reconvert to hex string makes different information

Tags: node.js, hex, buffer, node-modules

I have this using Buffer in node.

```
string hex_message = "7E01000036015211601385025E";

var chunk = Buffer.from(hex_message, 'hex'); // 

var message = chunk.toString('utf-8'); // 

var bu = Buffer.from(message, 'utf-8');

var message3 = bu.toString('hex').toUpperCase();

// 7E010000360152116013EFBFBD025E
```

Note that makes 7E010000360152116013**EFBFBD**025E

I want using string to pass buffer between microservices, and i want to convert all buffer in string, but in the other when I need to rebuild the buffer I got different information.

Answer (score 3):

This step here:

```
var message = chunk.toString('utf-8');
```

creates a problem because after calling this:

```
var chunk = Buffer.from(hex_message, 'hex');
```

the Buffer contains binary data.  If you do `console.log(chunk)`, you will see this:

```
<Buffer 7e 01 00 00 36 01 52 11 60 13 85 02 5e>
```

which shows the binary representation of your original hex string:

```
"7E01000036015211601385025E"
```

Calling `chunk.toString('utf-8')` on that Buffer containing the binary data will attempt to interpret it as utf-8, but that won't be correct on purely binary data. In fact, it will take your binary data and try to interpret it as something other than the pure binary data.  It will look at the incoming data and see utf-8 escape sequences in some places causing it to interpret the data wrongly.

---

When you say you want to pass the data between microservices, we need to know how you're passing it between the microservices and what the capabilities of that transport are.  For some transports, you can just send the binary Buffer directly (like with TCP).  For other transports, you have to encode it to something that transport can handle, in which case the original `hex_message` string is a safe way to send it.  You could also put the binary into an array of numbers and the use JSON to encode/decode it.

The point is that you have to either just send the original `hex_message` string which is likely safe with any transport you're using or you have to properly encode that to something your transport can handle and then properly decode it on the receiving end to get back the binary it represents.

---

To summarize, here are the initial steps:

You first need to decide what encoding you're going to use for whatever transport you are using to communicate with the microservice.  You need to pick an encoding that can properly represent your binary data.  To help you pick that encoding, we would have to know how you're sending the data and what types of encoding it can handle.

Then, you need to take your ascii hex data and properly convert it to the desired encoding.

And here are some options for encoding:

1. Just send the original `hex_message` string you started with since the whole purpose of the "hex" encoding is to represent binary data in plain ascii strings.  This is likely safe with any transport you're using between microservices.  The receiving end can process the ascii string it receives to a binary buffer if required to use it.
2. Put the binary data into an array of numbers and encode that array as JSON and send the JSON.  Though sending the hex string in option #1 will likely be more efficient as it is represented in fewer bytes and is already available.
3. If your transport is capable of sending/receiving binary (which TCP can), then you can do `const chunk = Buffer.from(hex_message, 'hex');` and send the binary data in the Buffer directly.  The receiving end will get the binary Buffer and can then treat that according to its needs.